# Do MTA monthly passes work in NJ?

Tags: public-transport, new-york-city, nj-transit

I've lived in Manhattan for a few years and am now going to be in Hoboken for a few months. However, I'll still be commuting to Manhattan every day for work. I'm not at all familiar with transit to NJ.

Will my MTA monthly pass work for NJ transit buses? (doubt it, but I suppose it can't hurt to ask) What about the PATH trains to NJ? 
Can the balance on an NYC metrocard at least be used on NJ transit buses?

Comment: It isn't about what state you're in, but who the operator is the service is. If the operator accepts MTA passes, you're fine, but I'm not aware of any authority other than MTA which does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your MetroCard to pay for the PATH train. [The fare is currently $2.75 one way](https://www.panynj.gov/path/fares.html). Note that there is no free transfer between PATH and MTA; you pay separate fares on each system.

No part of the New Jersey Transit system accepts MetroCard stored value or passes. They have a completely separate [fare system and tickets](https://www.njtransit.com/ti/ti_servlet.srv?hdnPageAction=BusTicketsTo).